# Can not read StandardOutput when Process call cmd batch in WindowsXP C# , but it does in Win7

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I use Process to call a batch cmd, and then read the output of the execution.Through the output lines, I analyze success or failed of the execution. All things work well in win7, but in WindowsXP, I cannot read any lines from standard output. I guarantee the batch file can work well by manual in WindowsXP command console window. The following is my code:

```
//this method is entrance of execution
public bool buildApk()
{
    string launch = "\"" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\SmartCon\start_up_build" + "\"";
    string output = ExecuteAsync(launch);
    return output.Contains("SUCCESS");
}

public static string ExecuteAsync(string dosCommand)
{
    string output = "";     
    StringBuilder sbOutput=new StringBuilder ("");

    if (dosCommand != null && dosCommand != "")
    {
        Process process = new Process();     
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";      
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + dosCommand;   
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;   
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;   
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;     
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        try
        {
            if (process.Start())       
            {
                while (!process.HasExited )
                {
                    string d = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();//here I read nothing in windowxp, but in win7, all things go well
                    sbOutput.Append(d);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (process != null)
            {
                process.Close();
                process.Dispose();
                process = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return sbOutput .ToString ();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should also try to read `StandardError` to see if there's an error being produced when you run on XP.

Comment: Yeah, as @SimonMcKenzie said, I read StandardError, find that root cause is the following code line:

Comment: As @SimonMcKenzie said, I add a line to read StandardError , find that root cause is the following code line:
    string launch = "\"" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\SmartCon\start_up_build" + "\"";

In WindowsXP,System.Environment.CurrentDirectory may be changed if you use OpenDialog to select file, but in Win7 it does not. So I add a line to set WorkingDirectory of StartInfo. All things work well.